# How to update the status to Paid and update Amount Paid and Amount Due in XERO using API - PHP

Tags: php, laravel, xero-api

I am trying to update an Invoice in XERO by using the XERO-API. I am able to save the invoice as 'Draft' which is an outstanding amount that the customer to pay. When the payment is done, I want to send a request to the Xero and want to change the status to 'PAID'; amountDue = '$ 0.00' and AmountPaid = '$XX.xx'. I am not able to update this info and I am working on PHP. There is not much discussion/ research on this either.

```
$refXero  = 'INV-123456';
$invoices =  $xero->loadByGUID('Accounting\\Invoice', $refXero );

    **//I am getting errors from here onwards:-** 

$invoices->setAmountDue('0');
$invoices->setAmountPaid('50.00');
$invoices->setStatus('PAID');
$invoices->setDate('2019-10-15');
$invoices->save();
```

**The error I am getting is 'Call to undefined method XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoice::setAmountDue()'**

How can I send this info and update this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To make a Xero invoice as PAID, you'll need to create a payment for the appropriate amount using the /payments endpoint. Once the sum of the payments against an invoice matches the total of the invoice, it'll be set to PAID.

Documentation of the /payments endpoint is here:

https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/payments#PUT

...but it probably already exists in the SDK you're using. Note you'll need to have set the invoice to be AUTHORISED before you can successfully make payments.

Answer (score 0):

My Invoice ref number is: **97661-Z** (Saved in my Database and XERO)

```
$currRefNumber = $request->input('update_payment_refNumber'); //**Z**
$refXero = $bookingID.'-'.$currRefNumber; //(**97661-Z**)
```

This Invoice Number 97661-Z is saved as Draft in the XERO.

So basically, when the Invoice is saved as a draft, it first needs to be updated as **Authorised** as below:-

```
$invoices = XeroPrivate::loadByGUID('Accounting\\Invoice', $refXero);
$invoices->setStatus(\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoice::INVOICE_STATUS_AUTHORISED);
$invoices->save();
```

The above will update the Invoice status from **Draft**  to **Awaiting Payment**

Now get the account code:-

```
$account = XeroPrivate::loadByGUID('Accounting\\Account', '880');
$dateInstance = new \DateTime();
$newPayment = new \XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Payment();
              $newPayment
                        ->setInvoice($invoices)
                        ->setAccount($account)
                        ->setDate($dateInstance)
                        ->setAmount(600)
                        ->setIsReconciled(true)
                        ->setReference('Payment Received');

XeroPrivate::save($newPayment);
```

This will now change the **status = Paid** and will update the information **AccountDue = $0.00** and **AccountPaid = $600.00**

I hope this will help others if needed.